# Plotly range_slider limits

Tags: python, plotly

I run the code below to create a scatter with a range slider using plotly. This yields the following output - [image: here]

I want to make the scatter "tight", i.e no slack with no data on the sides. When I run the code from plotly's [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/range-slider/) there are no slacks (same notebook, same kernel).

When I add - `fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(range=[x[0],x[-1]]))` it update only the range of the graph but not the range of the slider. [image]

I would appreciate any advice.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = [datetime(2019, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(365)]
y = [1]  * 365
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="Pred", mode="markers"))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeselector=dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=6,
                     label="6m",
                     step="month",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="YTD",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="todate"),
                dict(count=1,
                     label="1y",
                     step="year",
                     stepmode="backward"),
                dict(step="all")
            ])
        ),
        rangeslider=dict(
            visible=True
        ),
        type="date"
    )
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the following line before `fig.show()`:

```
fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(range=[x[0],x[-1]],rangeslider=dict(range=[x[0],x[-1]])))
```

your graph should become:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Do. you happen to have an idea why the behavior differs from the  behavior in the example?

Comment: I think it's because there is a default padding set in plotly when it renders the html code of graph.

Comment: Thanks, I just wonder about the inconsistency with the documentation example

Comment: It is a known issue that can be "solved" by using `mode="lines"` instead of `mode="markers"`. More here - https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2909